# Why q-select cannot autofocus in a q-dialog? (Quasar V2)

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I simply copied the default dialog code from the quasar v2 documentation and inserted a `<q-select autofocus/>` . But it seems like the autofocus cannot be enabled for a select menu in a dialog. Is there any way to enable this? `<q-select autofocus/>` works fine as a component by itself though. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `<q-form>` between the `<q-dialog>` and `<q-select>` ?

Comment: It doesn't work as well. I found it weird as quasar v1 works alright...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is offered in 2.7.5

Refer to link [github issue](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/13831)

Comment: I commented on that fix - still doesn't work in 2.10 in iOS 16.1.1